# Как Visual c++ открыть и использовать конструктор окон Visual Studio(GUI)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, gui, visual-studio-2017

Знаю что в Visual studio для visual Bacic Есть конструктор окон.Как им пользоваться в проекте c++ или какой есть альтернативный бесплатный вариант создания GUI c++

P.S.(qt не подходит, как раз из-за того, что он платный)

Comment: В C++/Cx есть xaml, как в c#, но C++/Cx только для winRT (win 7 не поддерживается, и вменяемых способов прикрутить, кажется, не существуют). Можно писать UI через c# или visual Bacic, а потом через прослойку в виде C++/Cli. Насколько это хорошая идея, и спользует ли её кто-то в продакшене я не знаю.

Comment: сам пользуюсь visual studio 2008 express c++ там есть генератор windows forms c++ классная штука программы получаются хорошего качества ,работают в любом windows

Comment: У вас что коммерческий проект? Если, вам подходит GPL или LGPL лицензия, то Qt бесплатный, скачиваете и пользуетесь